# how do i setup reverse proxy game server?

Tags: networking, routing, nginx, vps

I first posted this question on Reddit which got deleted, after discussing with the mods they banned me. So I decided to give this community a try. If you don’t have the time or don’t want to please ignore my message.

I have been trying to get anti ddos for Team-speak, rust and future projects. I do not want to use a €15 hosting provider since i already have a strong server that I use for things such as minecraft:tcp shield, website:Cloudflare. Everything is already good to go all I need is some protection ( routing traffic through vps). So I bought the most cheapest vps for €4 and planned to use it as reverse proxy. I am currently using azure. The things I already tried are ( nginx stream , GRE, UFW nat, ip tables ) but didn’t work.

( GRE was not supported had to find out the hard way)

(nginx)

```
stream {
upstream rust {
    server my_ip:28015;
}

server {
    listen 28015;
proxy_pass rustudp;
}
upstream rust {
    server my_ip:28015;
}

server {
    listen 28015 udp;
proxy_pass rustudp;
}
upstream rust1 {
    server my_ip:28016;
}

server {
    listen 28016;
proxy_pass rust1;
}
upstream rust1udp {
    server my_ip:28016;
}

server {
    listen 28016;
proxy_pass rust1udp;
}
```

}

(Ip tables)

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 28015 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DNAT --to my_ip:28015
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp --dport 28015 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DNAT --to my_ip:28015
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 28016 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DNAT --to my_ip:28016
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp --dport 28016 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DNAT --to my_ip:28016
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE
```

If anyone can link a helpful guide into the right direction I would be really thankful since I wasn’t able to find any.

Answer (score 0):

just found the solution, wasnt even a hard one. removing -m conntrack and extra things solved my issue. dont know why no one was able to anwser but i got what i wanted :).

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 28015 -j DNAT --to-destination ip:28015
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 28015 -j DNAT --to-destination ip:28015
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 28016 -j DNAT --to-destination ip:28016
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 28016 -j DNAT --to-destination ip:28016
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```